# How do we separate variables from letters in shell scripting?

Tags: bash

I tried printing "Dogs are the best." with this bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

ANIMAL="Dog"
echo "$ANIMALs are the best."
exit
```

However, I got " are the best." printed out instead because the `s` in `$ANIMALS` is not separated from the variable. How do I separate it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With braces: `echo "${ANIMAL}s are the best."`

With quotes: `echo "$ANIMAL"'s are the best.'`

With printf: `printf '%ss are the best.\n' "$ANIMAL"`

I wouldn't use the quotes one most of the time. I don't find it readable, but it's good to be aware of.

Comment: That mixing of quotes example makes it look like it will print out `Dog's are the best.` even though obviously running it will show that it wont.

Comment: Ah, the anonymous downvoter. The papercut of answering questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9):

Just surround the variable's name with curly braces.

```
#!/bin/bash

ANIMAL="Dog"
echo "${ANIMAL}s are the best."
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash


ANIMAL="Dog"
echo "${ANIMAL}s are the best."
exit
```

The answer is no longer unique, but correct...

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I think you're drastically missing the point of the questoin; obviously, you can pluralize the word in the variable, but the question is how to echo a variable when a character should immediately follow the variable.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables : Didn't realize why I was getting downvotes :(. THanks for pointing that out... Corrected my answer...

Comment: This answer is correct for PHP syntax, but not for the shell. In shell, the output would be `{Dog}s are the best.` The dollar sign needs to be outside the curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

Move your variable outside the quotes in echo :

```
#!/bin/bash

ANIMAL="Dog"
echo $ANIMAL"s are the best."
exit
```

OR :

```
#!/bin/bash

ANIMAL="Dog"
echo "${ANIMAL}s are the best."
exit
```

Both worked for me

Comment: Don't do the first one. Ref: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Answer (score 2):

Useless quotation, useless exit. A finished script needs no help to exit but the exit will bite you when sourcing that script.

```
ANIMAL=Dog
echo ${ANIMAL}s are the best.
```

Comment: The quotes are far from useless. They prevent wordsplitting. The fact that the output *appears* the same only obscures what's going on beneath the surface. An experienced scripter might choose not to use quotes for specific contexts, but the average StackOverflow reader should not be led this way…

Comment: @kojiro: There is no wordsplitting going on without quotes, so they can't prevent it. Since many languages use quotes around every string and need those, using them extensively in scripts mimics those languages and is only a modern form of cargo cult, misleading especially beginners and rare users.

Comment: No, the wordsplitting is definitely going on. If you just happen to have one space between unquoted words then you don't see it, because the expansion after wordsplitting also happens to use one space. But if, for example, you set `ANIMAL=$'Dog\nand   cat'` and you echo it without quotes, you'll just get `Dog and cat` as output.

Comment: @kojiro: If, if, if - but that wasn't the case so it is all YAGNI, but a missed opportunity to show that strings don't need quotation in the shell.

Comment: If users actually asked their real questions on StackOverflow, then we wouldn't need to have discussions like this. But they don't, and we do. It's not YAGNI. It's an [extremely common pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: @kojiro: It is a pitfall because people don't know when they need quotes, in which circumstances. A "quote always"-policy is no solution to that problem.